# Ubuntu php extension missing, but I have installed

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, apt

I am getting a "the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system" when I am running composer on Ubuntu. I have however installed this extension with

```
sudo apt-get install php5-intl
```

It is installed because when I try and install it says it already has the latest version.

I installed a later version of PHP. Could that have something to do with it? When I run "php -m" I do not see INTL as one of the enabled extensions. It is loading the latest PHP version though.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you install your other version of PHP?

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-compat`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get upgrade`
`sudo apt-get install php5 # this will pull php5.6 package`

Comment: So my guess is that the `php5-intl` package is not on the ondrej/php5-compat repository. I think it is pulling from default ubuntu ppa and as such is not being installed to the correct location, nor is the php.ini being updated. You may be better off installing via pecl.

Comment: Does `sudo php5enmod intl` help?

Comment: No luck I'm afraid. Just had to reinstall everything. PECL was causing more errors than was manageable so just started from scratch.